# How to return earliest date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to look at the dates of 5 columns of qualification then enter the earliest date in a new column then if it is before today's date turn it red and highlight it.

I can do the second in conditional formatting but I am unsure how to get the first part accomplished.

Comment: I don't have Excel to hand to check, but it looks like a combination of the [MIN](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/MIN-function-58c5be73-9206-4d5a-965a-eb9f419ee535) function and [Use a formula to apply conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `MIN` function. You can select several cells in a row or you can list separate cells with a comma in between.

```
=MIN(A1:E1)
=MIN(A1,E1,F1,H1,K1)
```